# WINAPI / APIENTRY is not defined

Tags: c++, winapi

I've built a new dll project in VS 2012, 
I've copied some code from another project, 
everything is the same but...

WINAPI / APIENTRY is not defined.

They are residing in a file names minwindef.h
and I can't find where is it included in the source project, 
I don't want to include it manual. 
What should I change in the project in order for it to recognize this directive ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to include windows.h to get the required definitions, that's just the way Windows development works.

Comment: it is not included in the referenced project. I will check again.

Comment: StdAfx.h/.cpp is used when you have precompiled headers turned on. You don't need to use it, but you have to include windows.h if you're writing software that makes use of the Windows API functionality.